# Why converting list to dictionary does not work in python?

Tags: python

I have a program that should print like this. In the last part, I converted the list to dictionary, but it does not work

```
Enter rows of text for word counting. Empty row to quit.
I'm on a high way to hell
I'm on a high way to hell
It's going really well
Well it's only hell

a : 2 times
going : 1 times
hell : 3 times
high : 2 times
i'm : 2 times
it's : 2 times
on : 2 times
only : 1 times
really : 1 times
to : 2 times
way : 2 times
well : 2 times
```

I wrote this code but does not give the expected output

```
def word_count(str):
    counts = dict()
    words = str.split()

    for word in words:
       if word in counts:
          counts[word] += 1
       else:
          counts[word] = 1
    return counts


def listToString(s):
    str1 = ""
    for ele in s:
        str1 += ele
    return str1

def Convert(a):

        it = iter(a)
        res_dct = dict(zip(it, it))
        return res_dct

def main():

    print("Enter rows of text for word counting. Empty row to quit.")

    user_values = []
    prompt = ""
    line = input(prompt)

    while line:
        user_values.append(line)
        line = input(prompt)

    user_list=(listToString(user_values))

    user_list=word_count(user_list)
    user_list = Convert(user_list)

    for k, v in sorted(user_list.items()):  # sorts
        print(k," : ",v," times")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? The total count for each word appears to be correct?

Comment: Have you heard of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: As an aside, don't create a string from a list the way you do in `listToString(s)` use `''.join(mylist)`

Comment: @Skully yes, the total count of each word in alphabetic order

Comment: `user_list = listToString(...)` is a _string_. `user_list = word_count(...)` overwrites this string with a dict. `Convert()` doesn't do anything as far as I can see.

Comment: @Jab collections.counter is not allowed in this problem!

Answer (score 1):

#### Fix

- `listToString` method join sentences without space, so you create new words. Just do `user_list = " ".join(user_values)`
- don't need `Convert` at all
- specify a key sorter that use the lowercase version, because if not uppercase letters come before  `sorted(user_list.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower())`

```
def main():
    print("Enter rows of text for word counting. Empty row to quit.")
    user_values = []
    line = input(">")
    while line:
        user_values.append(line)
        line = input(">")

    user_list = " ".join(user_values)
    user_list = word_count(user_list)

for k, v in sorted(user_list.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower()):
        print(k, " : ", v, " times")
```

---

#### Improve

With `collections.Counter`

```
def main():
    print("Enter rows of text for word counting. Empty row to quit.")
    user_values = []
    line = input(">")
    while line:
        user_values.append(line)
        line = input(">")

    user_list = Counter(" ".join(user_values).split())
    for k, v in user_list.most_common():
        print(k, " : ", v, " times")
```

Comment: Collections. counter was not allowed for this program. But the program still does not work alphabetically after sorting!

Comment: @Mun oh you want to wort the words in lexicographical (alphabetical) order ?

Comment: @Mun is `collections.defaultdict` allowed  for word_count method ?

Comment: don't know about that, I tried with collections.counter automatic test said its not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Your code can work except for a few of things:

`Convert` doesn't do what you think it should and it's totally superfluous.

`listToString` doesn't work right and can be replaced with `string.join()`

In `word_count` change `word` to lower case.

Something like this:

```
def word_count(str):
    counts = dict()
    words = str.split()

    for word in words:
       word = word.lower()
       if word in counts:
          counts[word] += 1
       else:
          counts[word] = 1
    return counts


def main():

    print("Enter rows of text for word counting. Empty row to quit.")

    user_values = []
    prompt = ""
    line = input(prompt)

    while line:
        user_values.append(line)
        line = input(prompt)

    user_list = " ".join(user_values)

    user_list=word_count(user_list)

    for k, v in sorted(user_list.items()):  # sorts
        print(k," : ",v," times")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```